# post affiliate pro request/response in XML

Tags: c#, xml, post, affiliate

I have 2 questions:

- Is it possible to send request/get response from Pro Affiliate Pro 4 API (http://support.qualityunit.com/871709-Programmers-documentation), using c#?
- If the answer to my first question is "YES", could you please someone give me an example of  xml request and response?

Answer (score 3):

people from QualityUnit answered to my questions:

> If you can't use php API, then the only way to send API request / get API response is using JSON request as explained here:
>   http://support.qualityunit.com/354854-C-NET-communication-with-API
>   JSON data model regarding PAP API is explained here:
>   http://support.qualityunit.com/110653-Data-model-JSON-description#355518